# Is There a C#.Net Equivalent to Objective-C's Selector

Tags: c#, objective-c, events, delegates, selector

This is a C#.net question for Objective-C developers who also work with C#.Net

As you know, **Objective-C** you can parse a **method** name to a **Selector**; and the method can also belong to an **outside class**.

I would like to be able to use this type of method in C#.Net as it would be a lot cleaner than creating loads of **Events** which can become messy and hard to manage.

If this is possible, how can I achieve this? Thank you!

**Example:**

```
public class Main
{
    public void MyProcess(Callback toMethod)
    {
        // do some fancy stuff and send it to callback object       
        toMethod(result);
    }
}

public class Something
{
    public void RunMethod()
    {
        MyProcess(Method1);
        MyProcess(Method2);
    }

    private void Method1(object result)
    {
        // do stuff for this callback
    }

    private void Method2(object result)
    {
        // do stuff for this callback
    }
}
```

Comment: You've pretty much answered yourself in your tags: use delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Objective-C, but I think you want something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public void MyProcess(Action<object> toMethod, object result)
    {
        // do some fancy stuff and send it to callback object       
        toMethod(result);
    }
}

public class Something
{
    public void RunMethod()
    {
        object result = new object();
        MyProcess(Method1, result);
        MyProcess(Method2, result);
    }

    private void Method1(object result)
    {
        // do stuff for this callback
    }

    private void Method2(object result)
    {
        // do stuff for this callback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).  Based on the code in your question, you would declare a delegate:

```
public delegate void MethodDelegate(object result);
```

The signature of the process method changes to the following:

```
public void MyProcess(MethodDelegate toMethod)
{
    // do some fancy stuff and send it to callback object       
    toMethod(result);
}
```

And then you would call process

```
public void RunMethod()
{
    MyProcess(new MethodDelegate(Method1));
    MyProcess(new MethodDelegate(Method1));
}
```